# How to make a button hidden and appear after a certain amount of date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm wanting to make a button to be hidden for a selected amount of time. The website that I've built is about hotel reservation system which allows user to book a hotel. The booking details that the users will need to put are the phone number, number of nights, number of rooms and the booking date.

The checkout date will be done based on a calculation made from the number of nights, number of rooms and the booking date that the user enters.

However, my main idea is to implement something that disables or hides the book now button from the user after they have booked a hotel. And to make the button appear which is based on the checkout date. Just to make it clear that the users can book that hotel after the checking out date has finished...

The code that I have tried to do for this idea;

```
                    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `user_id`= ? AND id = ?");
                    $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $_SESSION['user_id'], $id);
                    $stmt -> execute();
                    $result = $stmt -> get_result();
                    $booking_info = $result -> fetch_assoc();



                $sql = "SELECT id FROM book WHERE hotel_id = '".$hotel_id."' AND user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";

                $thisresult = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                if($booking_info['check_out'] <= date('Y-m-d')){
                    echo "<button style=' ' type='submit'> <a href='booknow.php?id=".$id."'> Book now!</a></button>"; 
                }
                else if(mysqli_num_rows($thisresult)>=1){
                        echo "You have already booked this hotel!";
                } else {
                    echo "<button style=' ' type='submit'> <a href='booknow.php?id=".$id."'> Book now!</a></button>"; 
                }
                }
        ?>
```

Table name  book;

```
     id(int 11)
     user_id(int 11)
     hotel_id(int 11)
     phone(varchar 50)
     date(datetime)
     num_nights(int 60)
     num_rooms(int 4)
     check_out(date)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It would be very easy if you add condition in sql to check_out

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are looking for, in JavaScript, you can use the setInterval() function.

Example: setInterval('yourfunction', 1000);
1000 milliseconds = 1 second

To hide a button in HTML, have you tried CSS? You can add style="display: none;" as an attribute.

Comment: I'm looking for something that hides the button during after the checkin date and then reveals the button after the checkout date has finished. The JavaScript usin the milliseconds wont help me in this case...

Answer (score 0):

It is all about your if statement. Should be fixed as follows

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($thisresult)>=1){
     echo "You have already booked this hotel!";
 } else {
     if(strtotime($booking_info['check_out']) >= time()){
        //nothing to do here, button won't show up
    } else {
        echo "<button style=' ' type='submit'> <a href='booknow.php?id=".$id."'> Book now!</a></button>"; 
    }
}
```

Just leave a comment, if this does not work

Comment: It didn't work. I have made a booking and set the date to the 18/04/2017. When I put the code you provided, I have changed the date in the database and checked that the button doesn't appear before the 18nth...

Comment: @amir code is updated, can you try the final version and let me know?